# ¿Cómo mostrar un SplashScreen para decir que la aplicación está "cargando"?

Tags: android

Necesito mostrar un progressbar estilo loading, me explico:

EL primer activity que se lanza es un splashscreen, luego de este viene un activity en donde automáticamente comienza a funcionar la clase mplayer con una url externa. Sucede que tarda un tiempo variable (según estado de la red y otras condiciones) en aparecer el segundo activity y en ese lapsus muestra una pantalla negra. Es en ese momento que deseo agregar un loadig por mientras se obtiene la información de la url externa de la clase mplayer.

Muestro el código del layout de mi activity donde tengo el player.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.streamingcoop.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_noticias"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="NOTICIAS"
        android:textSize="@dimen/abc_action_bar_progress_bar_size" />

</LinearLayout>

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Deportes" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Política" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </TableRow>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/mi_loading"
        android:layout_width="748dp"
        android:layout_height="102dp"
        android:indeterminate="false" />

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Economía" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:text="Entretención" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/reproductor"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/stop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_pause" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/play"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_play"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Muestro el código del activity donde está el player.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    static MediaPlayer mPlayer;
    ImageButton buttonPlay;
    ImageButton buttonStop;
    String url = "url";
    Button btn_politica, btn_deportes, btn_espectaculo, btn_entretencion;
    ProgressBar progressbar;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //setContentView(R.layout.splash);//analiza el archivo XML, traduce a objetos cada componente,
        //le asigna los atributos, establece contenedores y todas las relaciones
        //padre e hijo necesarias.

        progressbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.mi_loading);
       // progressbar_splash=(ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.mi_loading_splash);
        progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        //Bloque de codigo para el streaming al cargar el activity
        mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                progressbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
               // progressbar_splash.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                 //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ya cargó!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }
        });
        try {
            mPlayer.setDataSource(url);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            mPlayer.prepare();

        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        mPlayer.start();
        //Finaliza bloque de codigo para cargar el streaming al inicio de la aplicacion+

        initialize();

        //Bloque de codigo para el streaming al presionar play
        buttonPlay = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.play);
        buttonPlay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    progressbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                      //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cargandooooooo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                });
                try {
                    mPlayer.setDataSource(url);
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (SecurityException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    mPlayer.prepare();
                    // progressbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.mi_loading);
                    //progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                mPlayer.start();
                // progressbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                buttonPlay.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                buttonStop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        });

        //Bloque de codigo para el streaming al presionar pause
        buttonStop = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.stop);
        buttonStop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (mPlayer != null && mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    mPlayer.stop();
                    //buttonPlay.setEnabled(true);
                    buttonPlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    buttonStop.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                   // progressbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void initialize() {
        btn_deportes = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn_deportes.setOnClickListener(this);

        btn_politica = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        btn_politica.setOnClickListener(this);

        btn_espectaculo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        btn_espectaculo.setOnClickListener(this);

        btn_entretencion = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        btn_entretencion.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button1:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, Activity_Noticias_Deportes.class));
                break;
            case R.id.button2:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, Activity_Noticias_Politica.class));
                break;
            case R.id.button3:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, Activity_Noticias_Economia.class));
                break;
            case R.id.button4:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, Activity_Noticias_Entretencion.class));
                break;
        }
    }
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (mPlayer != null) {
            mPlayer.release();
            mPlayer = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Muestro el código del primer Activity, el Splash

public class Splash extends Activity {
    private AlertDialog.Builder mBuilderWait;
    private static final long SPLASH_SCREEN_DELAY = 2000;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
   // progressbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.mi_loading);
   // lanzarthread();
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Start the next activity


            Intent mainIntent = new Intent().setClass(
                    Splash.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(mainIntent);

            // Close the activity so the user won't able to go back this
            // activity pressing Back button
            finish();
        }
    };
    // Simulate a long loading process on application startup.
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(task, SPLASH_SCREEN_DELAY);
}
private void lanzarthread() {
    Thread timer = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                sleep(2000); //se duerme por 2 segundos
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();//muestra error de ejecucion en consola
            } finally {//pase lo que pase debe saltar a la siguiente pantalla.
                Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class); //instanciamos el objeto Intent y lo inicializamos desde splash hasta MainActivity
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }

    };
    timer.start();
}
```

}

Comment: veo correcto tu código, unicamente agrega dentro de onClick() del botón play un: progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); el cual será invisible cuando se ejecute onPrepared() que ya tiene la linea de código:  progressbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); para hacerlo nuevamente invisible,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplemente podrías agregar un progressBar en tu Activity, por ejemplo:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SplashScreenActivity" >

                    <ProgressBar 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

y cuando tu video/mp3 este listo por medio del listener `setOnPreparedListener()` has el progressBar invisible:

```
mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener(){

    @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); // esconde el progressBar.
        }
    });
```

En el caso de tu ejemplo creas varias instancias de `MediaPlayer` lo cual es incorrecto, puedes tener sola una instancia durante la vida de la actividad, ve este [ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21343703/250260) :

```
  progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            try {
                //Bloque de codigo para el streaming al cargar el activity
                mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                mPlayer.setDataSource(url);
                mPlayer.prepare();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("ERROR",e.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ocurrio un ERROR!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    progressbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ya cargó!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    progressbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    mPlayer.start();
                }
            });
```

Esto sería tu código corregido:

```
public class VideoActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

        static MediaPlayer mPlayer;
        ImageButton buttonPlay;
        ImageButton buttonStop;
        String url = "http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/hosannatelugu.mp3";
        Button btn_politica, btn_deportes, btn_espectaculo, btn_entretencion;
        ProgressBar progressbar;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            //setContentView(R.layout.splash);//analiza el archivo XML, traduce a objetos cada componente,
            //le asigna los atributos, establece contenedores y todas las relaciones
            //padre e hijo necesarias.

            progressbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.mi_loading);
            // progressbar_splash=(ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.mi_loading_splash);
            progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            try {
                //Bloque de codigo para el streaming al cargar el activity
                mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                mPlayer.setDataSource(url);
                mPlayer.prepare();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("ERROR",e.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ocurrio un ERROR!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    progressbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ya cargó!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.i("VIDEO", "ProgressBar Invisible!");
                    progressbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    mPlayer.start();
                }
            });
            //Finaliza bloque de codigo para cargar el streaming al inicio de la aplicacion+
            initialize();
            //Bloque de codigo para el streaming al presionar play
            buttonPlay = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.play);
            buttonPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (mPlayer != null && !mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                        try {
                            Log.i("INFO", "ProgressBar Visible! =) ");
                            // Aquí se hace el progressBar visible y cuando                      este preparado el video para reproducción se ejectua onPrepared() que hace el progressBar invisible.
                            progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            mPlayer.prepare();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        buttonPlay.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        buttonStop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                }
            });

            //Bloque de codigo para el streaming al presionar pause
            buttonStop = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.stop);
            buttonStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (mPlayer != null && mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                        mPlayer.stop();
                        buttonPlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        buttonStop.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        private void initialize() {
            btn_deportes = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            btn_deportes.setOnClickListener(this);

            btn_politica = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
            btn_politica.setOnClickListener(this);

            btn_espectaculo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
            btn_espectaculo.setOnClickListener(this);

            btn_entretencion = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
            btn_entretencion.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.button1:
                    startActivity(new Intent(this, Activity_Noticias_Deportes.class));
                    break;
                case R.id.button2:
                    startActivity(new Intent(this, Activity_Noticias_Politica.class));
                    break;
                case R.id.button3:
                    startActivity(new Intent(this, Activity_Noticias_Economia.class));
                    break;
                case R.id.button4:
                     startActivity(new Intent(this, Activity_Noticias_Entretencion.class));
                    break;
            }
        }

        protected void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            if (mPlayer != null) {
                mPlayer.release();
                mPlayer = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Recuerda el permiso

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

ya que estas cargando tu recurso desde internet.

Comment: Gracias Elena lo que sucede es que en la activity inicial, la del Splash tengo programado que despues de 2 segundo se cierre y se abra la otra, pero pasa que trascurren los 2 segundos se cierra y aún no carga la activity del mplayer porque está cargando una url, y ese instante me muestra la pantalla negra, es ahí en donde quiero agregar el progressbar o sincronizar que se cierre el splash justo cuando esté ya cargada la URL, se entiende? 
quedo muy atento, saludos y muchas gracias.

Comment: Podrías agregar tu layout de la actividad que contiene tu player?

Comment: Elena, subí el código actualizando mi pregunta.
Saludos.

Comment: Perfecto, permiteme revisar y te doy una solución.

Comment: He editado mi respuesta, tu idea era correcta al estar preparado e iniciar la reproducción el progressBar se hace invisible, usa mi código corregido y tu aplicación funcionara correctamente incluyendo el pausar y reproducir nuevamente.

Comment: Elena muchas gracias por el tiempo y por la revisión de mi código, pero deseo que al momento de presionar el boton play y en el tiempo que tarda en cargar la url mostrar el progressbar, para eso sólo lo dejo como visible al presionar play? y luego tan solo con el  public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {}

va a desaparecer?

Comment: https://github.com/rvargassanhueza/MiRepositorio

ahi puede revisar mi projecto estimada Elena, y muchas gracias.

Comment: Exacto cuando el medio esta listo para reproducción, se hace tu progressbar invisible: progressbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);  dentro de onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp), permiteme revisar...

Comment: Elena, lo tengo así como me indicas pero aún no funciona, sucede que la app tiende a detenerse un momento al cargar el contenido de la url y muestra el progressbar como por una milesima de segundo junto antes del inicio de la reproducción. Todo los elementos del activity quedan congelados por un tiempo.

Comment: Descargue tu código comentado y funciona correctamente de hecho puedo poner pausa y play y se reproduce sin problemas de hecho realicé un cambio en el click del botón play, únicamente debe tener:                                 progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); y                               mPlayer.prepare();

Comment: Elena Muchisimas Gracias, estuve estudiando y fuí aplicando la clase AsyncTask y me resultó lo que necesitaba, actualizaré mi código para que lo revises... nuevamente muchisimas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es crear un Alert Dialog para mostrar un mensaje de espera utilizando un Thread.

Primero crearias tu AlertDialog declarándolo fuera de tu clase

```
private AlertDialog.Builder mBuilderWait;
```

Después inicializandolo, es importante no dejar la posibilidad de que pueda cancelarse el Dialog

```
mBuilderWait = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

mBuilderWait.setTitle(getString("Titulo del Alert"))
            .setMessage(getString("Tu texto de espera.."))
            .setCancelable(false);
```

Ahora mostraras el AlertDialog antes de que inicies el proceso

```
mBuilderWait.show();
```

y cuando termine

```
mBuilderWait.dismiss();
```

El Thread es para realizar un cambio a la interfaz en el mismo tiempo de ejecución, esto es mas que nada si hay un error.

Ejemplo:

```
try{

    //Tu codigo de carga con el AlertDialog de espera

}catch(Exception e){

    //En caso de error cambio al dialog en mismo tiempo de ejecucion

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                    mBuilderWait.setTitle(getString("Error"))
                                .setMessage(getString("Error de conexion al servidor"))
                                .setCancelable(false);
                                .setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                            dialog.cancel();
                                        }
                                 });
                mBuilderWait.show();

                }
    });

}
```

**Referencias:**

- [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable))
- [AlertDialog](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html)

Comment: Gracias Max, lo voy a revisar y te comento,
Saludos.

Comment: Mira, ya explican como hacerlo en http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14497448/how-to-display-alert-dialog-in-running-thread

Comment: Gracias Max, no me queda aún muy claro lo que realizaría esto, enviaría un mensaje mientras paso a la otra activity?, el código hace referencia a un context pero nosé cuál puede ser el context. Disculpa estoy comenzando con el desarrollo en Android.

Comment: No logro hacer funcionar lo que me indicas Max, nosé el error que cometo :(